# Is there any way to set ssl: CERT_NONE of javascript's websocket in webBrowser?

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

I'm making javascript's websocket client in webBrowser.

I've faced an SSL issue.

my client failed to connect to some servers.

I googled, and found some solutions. But, this solution is only for python.

python provides options like **"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE**

javascript's websocket provides only parameter protocol like **new WebSocket(url : String, protocol : String) : WebSocket**

Is there any way to use ssl option in javascript's websocket of webBrowser?
(I want to use default websocket, please don't recommend another library)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instruct the browser from within Javascript to automatically ignore certificate problems. Ignoring such errors  can only be done interactively by the user of the browser.